# How can I figure out which is my file manager system?

Tags: linux-mint, file-manager, nemo, file-management

Is there any command I can use to understand which is the file manager installed in a machine?

For instance, I'm using Linux Mint and I can use the command `nemo`. Now I'm connected to another machine and I don't know the file manager that is used on it.

Comment: need much more information.

Answer (score 2):

About the default file manager, like the one that opens when you click on a desktop folder: when the file manager opens, go to Help->About, that should have the information (if it's not already in the window's title).

Alternatively, if you are using a shortcut, inspect it (right-click, ...) to see the actual command invoked.

If you want to know the available file managers, that's another thing. One way to find out is to see what distribution you are running `cat /etc/issue` and then try find out what the default file manager is. It might also on the graphic environment.